# PHP - Delete last line from xml

Tags: php, xml

I have this XML file called **help_cat.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ROOT>
</ROOT>
```

I want to do something like delete `</ROOT>` from the XML add new content and give `</ROOT>` back at the end of the XML file.

But I have the problem with the first step. Delete `</ROOT>`.

I tried

```
<?php
    $file = "help_cat.xml";
    $lines = file($file);
    echo sizeof($lines)."<BR />";
    $last = sizeof($lines)-1; 
    echo $lines[$last]."<BR />";
    unset($lines[$last]);
?>
```

The script wrote well that there are 3 rows in the file, but can't delete last row. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: why not load the XML into dom and just insert new children? It's far safer than mangling the xml with string operations.

Comment: @MarcB I'm not so expierenced. I tried
`$xml2 = simplexml_load_file($file);
$xml2->ROOT->addChild("MYROOTCHILD", "myrootvalue");`
But I got `SimpleXMLElement::addChild(): Cannot add child. Parent is not a permanent member of the XML tree`

Comment: A clear example of how to do this is displayed here at Example #1: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php

Comment: Thank you. I found solution here. http://www.serverphorums.com/read.php?8,27645